# Pytorch Error: Optimizer got an Empty Parameter List on Linux server

Tags: python, pytorch

I am running FasterRCNN code and was experimenting with various backbones (resnet18...101). I have created FasterRCNN class with init function. While training on my linux server I am facing the "Empty Parameter" error (can be seen in the attached image 1)
[image: Empty Parameter Error over Server]

While the same code is running without any error on my local machine.
I am using Anaconda distribution 4.0.1 and Python 3.7 with pytorch 1.2
Below you can refer my code (model and train) -

```
class Faster_RCNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=2, backbone = 'mobilenet_v2', test= False):
        super(Faster_RCNN, self).__init__()
        self.classes = num_classes # replace the classifier with a new one, that has num_classes 2 for our use.
        # 1 class (bar) + background 
        self.test = test
        self.backbone = backbone
        print('....Initializing Model....\n')
        print(f'....This model uses {self.backbone} as backbone....\n')
        if self.backbone == 'mobilenet_v2':        
            backbone = torchvision.models.mobilenet_v2(pretrained=True).features
            backbone.out_channels = 1280
            anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128),),
                                       aspect_ratios=((1.0),))
            roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                    output_size=7,
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)
            self.model = FasterRCNN(backbone,
                       num_classes=2,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)


        if self.backbone == 'resnet18':
            bb = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
            backbone = nn.Sequential(*list(bb.children())[:-2])
            backbone.out_channels = 512
            anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128),),
                                       aspect_ratios=((1.0),))
            roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                    output_size=7,
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)
            self.model = FasterRCNN(backbone,
                       num_classes=2,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)

        if self.backbone == 'resnet34':
            bb = torchvision.models.resnet34(pretrained=True)
            backbone = nn.Sequential(*list(bb.children())[:-2])
            backbone.out_channels = 512
            anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128),),
                                       aspect_ratios=((1.0),))
            roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                    output_size=7,
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)
            self.model = FasterRCNN(backbone,
                       num_classes=2,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)
        if self.backbone == 'resnet50':
            bb = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
            backbone = nn.Sequential(*list(bb.children())[:-2])
            backbone.out_channels = 2048
            anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128),),
                                       aspect_ratios=((1.0),))
            roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                    output_size=7,
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)
            self.model = FasterRCNN(backbone,
                       num_classes=2,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)
        if self.backbone == 'resnet101':
            bb = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
            backbone = nn.Sequential(*list(bb.children())[:-2])
            backbone.out_channels = 2048
            anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(sizes=((32, 64, 128),),
                                       aspect_ratios=((1.0),))
            roi_pooler = torchvision.ops.MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=[0],
                                                    output_size=7,
                                                    sampling_ratio=2)
            self.model = FasterRCNN(backbone,
                       num_classes=2,
                       rpn_anchor_generator=anchor_generator,
                       box_roi_pool=roi_pooler)

    def forward(self, x,y):
        if self.test:
            pred = self.model(x)
        else:
            pred = self.model(x,y)
        return pred
```

Here is the train code:

```
import dataloader
import model as md
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import torch
from torch.optim import Adam
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
import argparse
writer = SummaryWriter()

bkbone = ['resnet18','resenet34','resenet50','resnet101']

for bbone in bkbone:

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument("-b", "--backbone", required = False, default = bbone, help = "resenet18, resnet34, resnet50, resenet101 and mobilenet_v2 can be given")
    args = vars(ap.parse_args())
    epochs = 1000
    batch_size = 10
    lr = 0.005
    path = 'D:\\beantech_Data\\objtect_detection'
    # path = '/media/TBDataStudent/pankaj/beantech/object_detection'
    data= dataloader.Bar(root=path, batch_size=batch_size)

    model = md.Faster_RCNN(backbone=args['backbone']).cuda()
    model.train()

    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr = lr, weight_decay=0.0005)

    lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer,step_size=3,gamma=0.1)

    ### Train ###
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        loss_classifier=[]
        loss_box_reg =[]
        loss_objectness = []
        loss_rpn_box_reg = []
        Tloss = []

        for _, (img, label) in enumerate(data.train_loader):
            images = [image.cuda() for image in img ]
            for i in range(len(label)):
                label[i]['boxes']=label[i]['boxes'].cuda()
                label[i]['labels']=label[i]['labels'].cuda()
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            output = model(images, label)

            l1, l2, l3, l4 = output
            loss_classifier.append(output[l1].item())
            loss_box_reg.append(output[l2].item())
            loss_objectness.append(output[l3].item())
            loss_rpn_box_reg.append(output[l4].item())

            loss = sum(list(output.values()))
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            Tloss.append(loss.item())    

        writer.add_scalar(l1, np.mean(loss_classifier), epoch)
        writer.add_scalar(l2, np.mean(loss_box_reg), epoch)
        writer.add_scalar(l3, np.mean(loss_objectness), epoch)
        writer.add_scalar(l4, np.mean(loss_rpn_box_reg), epoch)
        writer.add_scalar('Total Loss', np.mean(Tloss), epoch)

        print(f'\n\n --{l1}: {np.mean(loss_classifier)}\n --{l2}: {np.mean(loss_box_reg)}\n --{l3}: {np.mean(loss_objectness)}\n --{l4}: {np.mean(loss_rpn_box_reg)}')
        print(f'Total loss of epoch {epoch}is: {np.mean(Tloss)}')
        writer.close()

    torch.save(model.state_dict(), f'FasterRCNN_{args["backbone"]}'+'.pt')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was pytorch version mismatch. I updated the server with latest pytorch and everything is running smooth.
thanks everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the code on your server, because you're definitely not running the train code you showed us, based on the error. In your code, you pass `model.parameters()` to the optimizer:

```py
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr = lr, weight_decay=0.0005)
```

but in the error message (which you posted as an image, and this is strongly discouraged), it says that line 36:

```py
optimizer = Adam(param, lr = lr, weight_decay=0.0005)
```

What is `param`?

Comment: I fixed the problem. The problem was with pytorch library. I updated the package and now everything is working fine. I think the server was not updated for very long. Also, can you tell me why you are advising (in a rude manner) not to pose error messages in the image?

Comment: @PankajMishra sorry if it sounded as rude, didn't mean that (updated it); but some of us are a little bit tired of this :) Not posting code as image is an [official recommendation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/4228275) and there are plenty of reasons to not doing that and you can see them all [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4228275).

Comment: @PankajMishra also, the code on your server and the one you posted in the question are different. Could you clarify on that? In addition, can you provide the version mismatch? It shouldn't be the reason for this type of error, unless you're talking about pre-1.0 vs. 1.2, and if it isn't, perhaps it is a bug worth opening an issue.